# Borel sigma-algebra for compacts

Tags: measure-theory, algebras

How can we show that the borel sigma-algebra on the interval (0, 1] is the smallest sigma-algebra that contains compact sets ?

Comment: Use the definition of "Borel sigma-algebra".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $(0,1]$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$, we know compactness is equivalent to being closed and bounded.  Since every subset of $(0,1]$ is bounded, this implies subsets of $(0,1]$ are compact if and only if they are closed.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of closed (i.e., compact) subsets of $(0,1]$.  Suppose by contradiction that there is a smaller $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}'$ than the Borel $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\mathcal{C}$.

Since $\mathcal{B}'$ contains $\mathcal{C}$ and it is also closed under set complements, $\mathcal{B}'$ contains all open sets in $(0,1]$.  But then this is a $\sigma$-algebra that's smaller than the Borel $\sigma$-algebra which contains the open sets, and this is a clear contradiction.  So $\mathcal{B}'$ doesn't exist, and thus the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the closed subsets of $(0,1]$, and thus the compact subsets of $(0,1]$.

Comment: ok. thanks. But, for the same problem, is it not redundant contain open intervals (a,b); or closed intervals [a,b]; or open sets; or closed sets? are there difference between closed sets and closed intervals in this case?

Comment: @ProbabilidadeEstatística Yes, there is a difference.  The set $[2,3] \cup [4, 20]$ is closed, but it's not a closed interval.  There is a theorem which can be proved with a little bit of work that shows every non-empty open set in $\Bbb R$ is a countable union of pairwise disjoint open intervals.  So if the open intervals are in your $\sigma$-algebra, so is every open set.

Comment: it means i can show the borel sigma-algebra on the interval (0, 1] is the smallest sigma-algebra that contains open intervals (a,b); or closed intervals [a,b]; or open sets; or closed sets and compact sets, simultaneously ?

Comment: @ProbabilidadeEstatística You can show that it's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets, or the open intervals, or closed sets.  I'm not entirely sure if that means you can show it is the smallest interval that contains closed intervals.  To do this, you'd need to know that closed sets are "generated" by closed intervals.  I don't know if closed intervals generate all closed sets in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

The $\sigma$-algebra generated by the compacts contains every open subinterval, so it contains every open subset.  Therefore, it contains the Borel sets.